# Humidity sensor always on after install

Tags: electrical

I am installing a Leviton in wall humidity sensor for a fan in a bathroom (https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-Decora-In-Wall-Humidity-Sensor-for-Bathroom-Exhaust-Fan-Control-Switch-1-4-HP-Residential-Grade-Single-Pole-White-R02-DHS05-1LM/324646573b). I've wired up the sensor as shown with ground-ground neural-neutral and black-black black to black but the fan is continually on and no LED ever lights up on the sensor. I've tried swapping the blacks but same result. I am at a lost of what to do from here. Thanks for any help

Comment: According to the HD site, that product is no longer available. How about a link to the Leviton install docs for it, instead. How about a picture of your actual install so we can double check your work? (You have no idea how many times I've thought I did it right, only to have someone else ask, "hey, this looks weird, you sure it's right?", then I realize I did it wrong...)